# Python IndentationError: too many levels of indentation

Tags: python

I've a part of my python program which is generated, the generated codes contains a lot of nested `if` / `else`, my problem is that a lot can be too much and I got this Error when running my code:

> IndentationError: too many levels of indentation

I've read that this was some limitation defined on the low level of the python interpreter, does anybody know how I can find a workaround for it? Some interpreter parameters would be fine, the only [solution proposal](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/325942/) I've found suggests to recompile Python in order to set a different value for the `MAXINDENT` constant, which is not exactly what I'm dreaming of.

**EDIT** : The code is a big bunch of nested `if...else` , it's dirty but it was the quickest I found to port a complex decision tree to Python. I know how dirty it is; I did not write it myself — I did not even plan to edit it (I would rather touch the generator).

I know I can modelize this decision tree in other fashions. What I would like is a way simpler than that, like tweaking the interpretor if possible.

**EDIT 2** : Now I've done some refactoring, and my tree is stored as a dictionary: The loading of the file gives a new error :

> s_push: parser stack overflow
>   MemoryError

Here again I found a resource suggesting [some tweaks of the interpreter's headers](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/issue3971-s-push-parser-stack-overflow-MemoryError-td676301.html).

---

Comment: wow! didn't know that was a max indentation in python! seems kind of silly to put a constraint on that. the link you gave us says its set to 100 though....you've exceeded 100 levels of indentation? refactor your code man! just take like the inner 50% and throw it in a function

Comment: I can't imagine how could you have reached more than 100 levels of indentation.

Comment: Tried jython: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

Comment: I might be wrong... but that many levels of nested `if .. else` seem to whisper to my ear **[RECURSION!!!](http://rlv.zcache.com/recursion_t_shirt-p235431290642472270zvf1f_400.jpg)**

Comment: Could we see what the generated code looks like? Or perhaps the generator?

Comment: I would change the generator to work differently.

Comment: Wow!! I've been a long time Pythoneer and didn't even know there was this limitation!! Time for a refactor!!

Comment: It's a GOOD thing to not know about this.  My brain has been tainted with needless info ;)

Comment: `Flat is better than nested.`

Comment: Is the code generator using `else: if` where it should be using `elif`? That would add a level of indentation for each step.

Comment: Guys I didn't know how you could think someone could write by hand 100 levels of indent by pure dumbness ... I did not do that (see edit in the question). Thanks for the few suggesting to put some changes on the generator, I'm gonna give a look to that.

Comment: See my edit -> the refacto didn't change anything (maybe the label of the error)

Comment: how your decision tree is looked like? You can have deeply nested structures that are generated dynamically e.g., ~100 nested-levels list leads to `parser stack overflow` as a string literal but it works if you create it dynamically e.g., from json-text https://ideone.com/OhfoX

Comment: I've more than 100 nested level, I'm gonna try this, thanks.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian post your comment as an answer, my decision tree was a python dictionnary, few hacks transformed it into a string that loads perfectly through json.loads. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have deeply nested structures that are generated dynamically e.g., ~100 nested-levels list leads to `s_push: parser stack overflow` as a string literal but it works if you create it dynamically from json-text, [example](http://ideone.com/OhfoX):

```
import ast
import json

N = 100
s = "["*N + "123" +"]"*N

L1 = json.loads(s)
def flatten(L):
    for el in L:
        try:
            for item in flatten(el):
                yield item
        except TypeError:
            yield el
assert next(flatten(L1)) == 123
print("json ok")

L2 = ast.literal_eval(s) # raises MemoryError
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick, I've just had to put some quotes around my dictionnary object and that works correctly after a json.loads call

Answer (score 3):

Your generator is producing bad code. You should treat this exactly as you would if it were producing syntactically invalid code.

Use functions, dictionary dispatching and any other thing that might occur to you to reduce the depth.

OTOH, thanks for showing me that Python does really have a maximum depth. I didn't know that. :)

Comment: Refacto leads to something similar, please see "EDIT 2" in my question... The dictionnary I'm using tends to be as big as the nested if.

Answer (score 1):

As for @warvariuc answer, the best thing to do would be to split your if-else sequences into several functions - one function for each "if-elif-else" sequence, with an authomated generated name.

Python will have to parse all functions in order for it to be able to call then in an arbitrary order, so the outermost "if-else" pair also has to be put in a function, which would be called at the end of the file.

In other words, the generated code you have now, that looks like this:

```
if bla:
    if ble:
        #bla
    else:
        #bli
elif ble:
    #bli
```

should be generated to look like this instead:

```
def main(state):
    if bla:
        main_1(state)
    elif ble:
        #bli

def main_1(state):
    if ble:
        #bla
    else:
        #bli

main()
```