# How can I avoid "IndentationError: too many levels of indentation" from deeply nested for loops?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am doing a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) question for programming practice in order to self-teach myself. I know perfectly well *how* to do the question mathematically, *as well as* how to do it programmatically.

However, I have to have come up with some insane code to do it; 100 nested loops and Python hilariously raises this error, and probably rightfully so,  on 100 levels of indentation:

```
IndentationError: too many levels of indentation



tally = 0
ceiling = 100
for integer_1 in range(0, 100, 1):
    for integer_2 in range(0, 100 - integer_1, 2):
        for integer_3 in range(0, 100 - integer_1 - integer_2, 3):
            for integer_4 ....
                for integer_5 ....
                    etc.
                        etc.
                            all the way to integer_100
```

I have looked through google for solutions but this issue is so rare it has almost no literature on the subject and I could only find this other stack overflow question ( [Python IndentationError: too many levels of indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439572/python-indentationerror-too-many-levels-of-indentation) ) which I could not find much useful in for my question.

My question is - is there a way to take my solution and find some workaround or refactor it in a way that has it work? I am truly stumped.

Comment: Shoot - sorry guys I had a mistake in the ranges. Fixed now

Comment: hah just have to say, if you have 100 nested loops, there's gotta be a better way...

Comment: this looks brute-forcey, and whichever euler question it is, i'll bet there is a smarter way to do it.  a lot of those questions are based more around mathematical insights.

Comment: Hahahaha thats what I thought too. But this is the only thing that occurred to me. Once I solve the question I have access to other peoples' solutions and can see what I don't know.

Comment: @wim it is *kind* of brute-force. Brute force would not adjust the upper bounds in the ranges, however my solution does, so my system loops exactly the number of times as there are ways to reach 100 (which is not brute force) - but I do get your point.

Comment: There HAS to be a better way to do this. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget for your interest, the question is number 76. However, please don't give me direct tips on how to do the question as my interest is not completing the question, it is about being challenged by hard problems which will lead me to think critically

Comment: @wim's point is that this is brute force in that you're going to every valid permutation of the valid sets of numbers; in other words, there's probably a better mathematical way than checking each and every set.

Comment: Refactoring each loop into a separate function will always work. And then, if you look for commonalities between the separate functions, you'll discover that the only difference between one loop at the next one down is the name of the function it calls, and the parameters it passes. Which means if you could merge the two somehow, the only difference would be the parameters it passes. Which means you _can_ merge the two. That's pretty much the general path to finding a recursive solution (although people who already think that way do most of it subconsciously).

Comment: And this can be done recursively . . .the number of ways to get to 100 can be based on the ways to get 99, which can be based on 98, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recursive solution should do nicely, though I'm certain there is an entirely different solution to the problem that doesn't require this kind of manipulation.

```
def count_rec(cursum, level):
    if level == 100:
        return 1
    res = 0
    for i in xrange(0, 100-cursum, level+1):
        res += count_rec(cursum+i, level+1)
    return res

print count_rec(0, 0)
```

Interestingly enough, if you *memoize* this function, it will actually have a reasonable running time (such is the power of *dynamic programming*). Have fun!

Comment: An example: for integer_5 in range(0, 100 - integer_1 - integer_2 - integer_3 - integer_4, 5). All loops follow this pattern.

Comment: But what's *inside* the innermost loop?

Comment: a simple "tally += 1". That's all - just to count how many times the entire system ticks over.

Comment: Haaaaaaaaha any possible suggestion?

Comment: You could write the world's largest list comprehension. Generate the ranges and then give them as a * argument to itertools.product and loop over that. It'll be very inefficient but it should work. This question kind of screams recursion.

Comment: I think you might actually run into the same problem with the list comprehension - try `eval('['*100 + ']'*100)` in your interpreter :)

Comment: I haven't used recursion yet in any programming, save for one function I copied from someone else for a question. This is the kind of reason I do the questions - to learn new things. Let me try this out...

Comment: If you're explicitly trying to learn new things, recursion is definitely a new thing worth learning.

Comment: @nneonneo yeah I run into "MemoryError" when I try eval('['*100 + ']'*100) in Python command line

Comment: Tested the code (yes, sometimes I post before testing); works fine. And, as a nice bonus, memoizing it makes this a perfectly reasonable, fast solution. Not memoizing it (i.e. the code I posted) makes it run forever. (@nebffa: Look up memoization and see if you can develop a memoization decorator in Python; they're really easy and extremely useful for Project Euler)

Comment: @nneonneo taking a look now. Thanks

Comment: ps just so you know from what you said, I will need to learn classes, decorators as well as recursion. Very useful but it will be a lot - would you recommend just going through some standard SO questions to learn or are there any online resources you already know of that are excellent atteaching/explaining any of these?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111857/what-did-you-use-to-teach-yourself-python#111864.

Comment: ps as I'm not too good with recursion yet, I can't fix your function - however it doesn't return correct values. The project eulers always have an example - it says there are 6 ways to add up to get 5. So I tried adjusting the numbers 100 to 5 in your function but it returns 12.

Comment: @nneonneo actually I worked it out - the function is just working out redunant solutions - e.g. 1 + 1 + 2 = 4, 1 + 2 + 1 = 4, 2 + 1 + 1 = 4, so subtracting by some choose notation should get rid of it I think

Comment: Not only an excellent answer but nneonneo's comments and suggestions helped me learn: **recursion**, **memoization**, **global variables** and **dictionaries**. Thankyou very much nneonneo, I have posted my code in the original answer (your code was slightly incorrect in that it counted a few too many cases, but without it I would never have been on the correct path nor learned what I needed to know).

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the indentation error is to put the loops in separate functions, each one nested only one level deep.

Alternatively, you could use recursion to call a function over and over again, each time with a smaller range and higher nesting level.

That being said, your algorithm will have an impossibly long running time no matter how you code it.   You need a better algorithm :-)

Comment: I'm not too sure how long it will actually take to run - I've adjusted the upper bounds on the ranges to reduce a long run time. You may be right, perhaps, and I may need to find another method :- ). However, I don't see how you would use recursion in this case without still having the problem with masive indentation. Can you provide a brief pseudocode example?

Comment: Fun fact: as a recursive, memoized function, it actually doesn't have an impossibly long running time, thanks to (implicit) dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

To do this using exactly your algorithm (restricting each next number to one that can possibly fit in the required sum), you really do need recursion - but the true brute force method can be a one-liner:

```
sum(sum(i) == 100 for i in itertools.product(xrange(100), repeat=100))
```

Naturally, this will be a fair bit slower than a true refactoring of your algorithm (in fact, as mentioned in the comments, it turns out to be intractable).

Comment: This would take longer than the age of the universe to run - that's why I can't do the brute force method.

Comment: @nebffa I don't think "longer than the age of the universe" is quite right; shouldn't take more than, say, a few weeks.

Comment: @lvc: No, 100**100 picoseconds is *a lot* longer than the current age of the universe -- that's the number of iterations you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective solution is based on the idea of arithmetic carrying.
You have lists of maximum values and steps,
and also a list of current values. For each time you want to update those 100 variables, you do this:

```
inc_index = -1
currentvalue[inc_index] += stepval[inc_index]
# I use >= rather than > here to replicate range()s behaviour that range(0,100) generates numbers from 0 to 99.
while currentvalue[inc_index] >= maxval[inc_index]:
    currentvalue[inc_index] = 0
    inc_index -= 1
    currentvalue[inc_index] += stepval[inc_index]
# now regenerate maxes for all subordinate indices
while inc_index < -1:
    maxval[inc_index + 1] = 100 - sum (currentvalue[:inc_index])
    inc_index += 1
```

When an IndexError is raised, you've finished looping (run out of 'digits' to carry into.)